# groovy filter unique value based on regex

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-groovy

groovy beginner here
i have input like :

```
def imglist = [
    "21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210216-0000-3617382",
    "21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-0000-17f6931","21.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-1626-4267925",
    "20.08-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-1031-1920a41","20.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-2053-5a1d378"
    ].sort().reverse(true)
```

```
for (String  solution : imglist) {

    println(solution)

}
```

which prints me

```
21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210216-0000-3617382
21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-0000-17f6931
21.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-1626-4267925
20.08-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-1031-1920a41
20.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-2053-5a1d378
```

as you can see i have two values 21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION, i need to keep only one with latest date 20210216

Comment: What regexp have you tried? How has it failed?

Comment: iam trying to figure out how to do it only thing i know that regex should be used

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`unique`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#unique(groovy.lang.Closure)) method on lists in groovy which might be suitable here. You could use regex or just plain `tokenize` depending on the shape of the data:

```
[
  "21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210216-0000-3617382",
  "21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-0000-17f6931",
  "21.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-1626-4267925",
  "20.08-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-1031-1920a41",
  "20.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-2053-5a1d378"
].sort()
 .reverse()
 .unique { a, b -> 
   a.tokenize('-').take(3).join() <=> b.tokenize('-').take(3).join()
 }.each { 
  println it
 }
```

which prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
21.02.0-RB-SOLUTION-20210216-0000-3617382
21.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-1626-4267925
20.08-RB-SOLUTION-20210215-1031-1920a41
20.02-RB-SOLUTION-20210212-2053-5a1d378
```

the `<=>` syntax is the groovy [spaceship operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spaceship_operator) and returns either -1, 0, or 1 depending on how the two items compare.